# Diagonalizable matrices over the complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having a hard time proving the following question:

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ be a diagonalizable matrix, show that there exists $B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ such that $B^{2018}=A$.
Is this also true for $A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$?

What i've tried so far: Since $A$ is diagonalizable we can express $A$ as $A=PDP^{−1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. I'm stuck at trying to prove that there exists $B∈M_{n×n}(\mathbb C)$ such that $B^{2018}=PDP^{−1}$

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Every diagonalizable matrix can be expressed as $$A=PDP^{-1}$$where $D$ is diagonal. Now find a diagonal matrix $D_1$ such that$$B=PD_1P^{-1}$$

**P.S.**

This problem can have no solution in $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$. Take $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

*You can refer to [Diagonalizable Matrices over Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix)*

Comment: I know that since $A$ is diagonalizable we can express $A$ as $A=PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. The part where I'm stuck at, though, is proving that there exists $B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ such that $B^{2018}=PDP^{-1}$

Comment: @user5842084 well what does $B$ being decomposed into $PD_1P^{-1}$, for the SAME $P$ mean? Can you then view the problem by switching the basis of the underlying vector space to get the equation $D_1^{2048} = D$? Then the requirement of it being of vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ becomes apparent.

Comment: It might also help to take a look at what $(PD_1P^{-1})^n$ simplifies to.

Comment: @dylan7 , if i get your direction: $A=PDP^{-1}$, so if the elements on the diagonal of $D$ are $d_1,\dots ,d_n$ then we can take $B=PD_1P^{-1}$, where the elements on the diagonal of $D_1$ are $\sqrt[2018]{d_1},\dots,\sqrt[2018]{d_n}$. This is legit, since $d_i\in\mathbb C$. In such way we get $B^{2018}=PD_1^{2018}P^{-1}=PDP^{-1}=A$ . If my solution is right, then that means the statement is also right for matrices over $\mathbb R$ and odd powers. Is there a way to solve it using the minimal polynomial or cayley-hamilton thm? because that's the subject of the worksheet that question is from...

Comment: Yes your solution is correct.  Another way to see this, is what I was getting at with my first comment, is since $A$ is diagonalizable, there exists a basis of eigenvectors of $A$, for the vector space it operates on. Thus changing $A$ to be w.r.t this basis of eigenvectors, $A$ is now a diagonal matrix, and thus the problem becomes $D_1^{2018} = D$, and so $D_1$ is also a diagonal matrix over this basis of eigenvectors of $A$.  And when you change back to the standard basis you get $ PD_1^{2048}P^{-1} = A$.

Comment: So in general it is not true for $\mathbb{R}$, since it is not algebraically close (as @Mostafa Ayaz proposed a counter-example), but it is true for Positive Semi-definite matrices on $\mathbb{R}$ with an inner product.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

Here is a solution utilizing the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, as the OP asked in the comments for.

Let $p(z)$ denote the minimal polynomial of $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. Since $A$ is diagonalizable $p(z) = (z-\lambda_1)...(z-\lambda_n)$, for distinct $\lambda_i$. Note $p(z)$ is also the characteristic polynomial of $A$ since $A$ is diagonalizable.

Let $B \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$, s.t. $A=B^{2018}$, then by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $\forall v \in \mathbb{C}^n$, $p(A)v = p(B^{2018})v = (B^{2018} - \lambda_1 I)...(B^{2018} - \lambda_n I)v = \boldsymbol 0$. Thus we know the polynomial $q(z) = (z^{2018} - \lambda_1)...(z^{2018} - \lambda_n)$ satisfies $\forall v \in \mathbb{C}^n, q(B)v = \boldsymbol 0$.

Let $v_1,...,v_n$ denote a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, then $q(B)v_i = p(A)v_i = \boldsymbol 0 $. If $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to eigenvector $v_i$, then only $(B^{2018} - \lambda_i I)v_i$ can equal $0 \implies Bv_i = \sqrt[2018]{\lambda_i}v_i$, by the algebraic closure property of $\mathbb{C}$.

Thus $B$ is diagonalizable over $v_1, ..., v_n$ and has eigenvalues $\sqrt[2018]{\lambda_1},...,\sqrt[2018]{\lambda_n}$. So $A = PDP^{-1} \implies B = PD_1P^{-1}$, where $D_1$ contains the eigenvalues of $B$ along its diagonal. $\Box$